# liquibase.bat not starting when executing

Tags: liquibase

I am evaluating Liquibase on my system. I have MySQL db ready to use.

The problem is I downloaded Liquibase from their website. It has a file named liquibase.bat. I am trying to run and it just flickers and disappears.

Actually it should start Liquibase and show its version.

Anybody has any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at the Liquibase.bat file and see what it is doing. If there is an `echo off` command in the file, you can comment that out and then you would be able to see each command as it runs and see where the problem is.

Are you trying to double-click on Liquibase.bat from Windows Explorer? If so, that is probably the problem. You should be running it from a command prompt.